# How to search for multiple items with the same name in datagridview

Tags: c#

Currently I can search for an item in column 1 of my datagridview. Ex: I search 2011-01 and the row containing the text gets highlighted. But this isn't the only 2011-01 in the datagridview. How can I search and highlight all rows containing this 2011-01 (can happen consequtively not all at once)

Here's my current code:

```
String searchVal = textBox1.Text.Trim();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
{
   if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchVal))
   {
      dataGridView2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
      dataGridView2.Rows[i].Selected = true;
      break; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to search for it in all rows of all columns? Or just all rows of the first column?

Comment: all rows of first column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should reiterate in the loop if you lose the `break`

PART 2:

Just add some logic at the if statement so only one the first row displayed, but the others are selected.  Let me know if that helps

```
String searchVal = textBox1.Text.Trim();
bool firstDisplayed = false;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
{
   if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchVal))
   {
      if (firstDisplayed == false)
      {
         dataGridView2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
         firstDisplayed = true;
      }
      dataGridView2.Rows[i].Selected = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: If I lose the break, the datagridview just scrolls to the LAST row containing the desired text. I want it to scroll to the first one, but still highlight all the other rows which have the text underneath it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag, @KSdev

Comment: @Newuser, added edit to answer for you.  Very simplistic approach that should accomplish what you want.